# How to find key value pair in a dictionary with values > 0 with key matching a certain string pattern?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

This is a dictionary,

```
Dictionary<string, uint> oSomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

oSomeDictionary.Add("dart1",1);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card2",1);
oSomeDictionary.Add("dart3",2);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card4",0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("dart5",3);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card6",1);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card7",0);
```

How to get the key/value pairs from `oSomeDictionary` with keys that starts with string "card" and has value greater than zero?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var result = oSomeDictionary.Where(r=> r.Key.StartsWith("card") && r.Value > 0);
```

for output:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

output:

```
Key: card2, Value: 1
Key: card6, Value: 1
```

*Remember to inlcude `using System.Linq`*

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) to filter then dictionary elements

```
var result = oSomeDictionary.Where(c=>c.Key.StartsWith("card")  && c.Value > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IEnumerable.Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) and [`String.StartsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) methods like;

```
Dictionary<string, uint> oSomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

oSomeDictionary.Add("dart1", 1);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card2", 1);
oSomeDictionary.Add("dart3", 2);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card4", 0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("dart5", 3);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card6", 1);
oSomeDictionary.Add("card7", 0);

var yourlist = oSomeDictionary.Where(n => n.Key.StartsWith("card") && n.Value > 0);

foreach (var i in yourlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", i.Key, i.Value);
}
```

Output will be:

```
Key: card2, Value: 1
Key: card6, Value: 1
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/cqIUcE).

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, uint> oSomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

            oSomeDictionary.Add("dart1", 1);
            oSomeDictionary.Add("card2", 1);
            oSomeDictionary.Add("dart3", 2);
            oSomeDictionary.Add("card4", 0);
            oSomeDictionary.Add("dart5", 3);
            oSomeDictionary.Add("card6", 1);
            oSomeDictionary.Add("card7", 0);

            var result = oSomeDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith("card") && pair.Value > 0 );
            foreach (var kvp in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
   }
```

Full working code above.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` implements `<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, so you can iterate through it using simple LINQ extension methods

```
var pairs = oSomeDictionary.Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith("card") && 
                                          pair.Value > 0);

Console.WriteLine (string.Join(Environment.NewLine, pairs));
```

prints:

```
[card2, 1]
[card6, 1]
```